# Uploading texture to GPU by PBO not working (OpenGL version 4.1)

Tags: macos, opengl, graphics, textures, pbo

I have read the famous tutorial [OpenGL Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html). I tested the sample code on my computer and it works (although with PBO on, its performance didn't improve but at least it's rendering correctly).

The problem is in the sample code the OpenGL context version is quite old (`Version: 2.1 INTEL-10.22.29`), and the OpenGL context version for my project is `version: 4.1 INTEL-10.22.29` which doesn't support extension `GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object` any more.

I have read this [Map and fill texture using PBO (OpenGL 3.3)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/map-and-fill-texture-using-pbo-opengl-3-3), so I change my code to:

```
// generating buffers and textures
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertex_array);
glBindVertexArray(_vertex_array);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexs_data), vertexs_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glGenBuffers(1, &_uv_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _uv_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uvs_data), uvs_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glGenBuffers(1, &_pixel_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, _pixel_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, DATA_SIZE, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
```

and render loop:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
// ======== start process PBO =========
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, _pixel_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, DATA_SIZE, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
GLubyte *ptr = (GLubyte*) glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
if( ptr != nullptr )
{
    cout<<"map pixel buffer success"<<endl;
    memcpy(ptr, DATA_SIZE, data );
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);   
}
// ========= end process PBO ==========

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
             _window_width, _window_height,
             0, GL_RGB,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data
);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
// draw commands goes here
```

My code is simply rendering a single color texture, if I comment the block from `======== start process PBO =========` to `========= end process PBO ==========` then everything goes well, but with this block, it just failed and all I get is a black screen. I already checked that the `glMapBuffer` works correctly and I successfully write the texture data to memory pointed by `ptr`( checking by print out its value ), but I can't figure out why I didn't get my expected result.

Thanks in advance.

My Environment:

```
OS: macOS sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB
```

Comment: So on MACOS the arguments to memcpy are (*dst, size, *src) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

This answer has been accepted, but it requires modifications. Here they are:

First my eye pointed out a cast from `(void*)`. No, this can't be, memcpy() will cast it again.

Then I arrived to `glTextImage2D`. And erroneously thought it can not be used with PBO (dam, I make too mistakes due to rush. I must relax...). Thanks **Nico Bolas** corrected me.

Then, slowly reading again, it was just a matter of not using a pointer to client data in glTextImage2D, change `data` to `0`

Docs say clearly about this last parameter:

> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the
>   GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a texture image
>   is specified, data is treated as a byte offset into the buffer
>   object's data store.

### OLD:

`GLubyte *ptr = (GLubyte*) glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);`

You are degenerating the returned pointer. Let it be `(void*)` if you only use it in a memcpy() command:
`void* ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);`

**EDIT:** (after I read again that you want to copy from PBO to a texture)

`glTextImage2D()` reads from a pointer *data* while `glTexSubImage2D()` can be used to read from a bound PBO. In this last case the last parameter to `glTexSubImage2D()`is an offset to that PBO (0 if no offset is needed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but replace `GLubyte *` with `void *` won't solve my problem, still get a black screen.

Comment: `glTexImage2D` also can read from a buffer. All pixel transfer operations can read from a buffer.

Comment: @NicolBolas Aaarg! Yes. You're right. So, change `data` to 0 in 'glTextImage2D' should suffice.

Comment: @Pipi2 Yes, changing `data` to `0` works! Thanks again! This solved my problem. So if I don't use PBO, the last parameter of `glTexImage2D` should be a pointer, and if I use PBO, then it should be an offset?